# How can I remove the icon of Telegram-Desktop from the dashboard?

Tags: icons, telegram

How can I completely delete this hidden icon of Telegram-Desktop after type `sudo snap remove Telegram-Desktop` into terminal from dash.

I do `sudo updatedb && locate Telegram` to see where they are.
In a addition, I have removed the *.desktop* file associated with it from the paths *~/.local/share/applications* as well *~/.config/menus/applications-merged*.
Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: How can I find it in /usr/share/applications？I'm sorry. I don't know which one.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and type:

> cd /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications

then type

> ls

it will list something like this

> mimeinfo.cache gnome-logs_gnome-logs.desktop  telegram-desktop_telegramdesktop.desktop

now your remove the telegram named file by typing

> sudo rm ./telegram-desktop_telegramdesktop.desktop

Answer (score 1):

I wasted too much time on that problem and came across every possible folder without success. Fortunately, I could remove it:

I finally tried MenuLibre, which listed the broken Telegram Desktop entry.

The provided command was

```
env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/telegram-desktop_telegramdesktop.desktop /snap/bin/telegram-desktop -- %u
```

so removing `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/telegram-desktop_telegramdesktop.desktop` finally did the job.